# How to make a baby sleep peacefully during an overnight Indian train journey?

Tags: trains, tips-and-tricks, children, sleeping, indian-railways

Indian train berths are quite narrow. Just enough for one person to sleep. My wife and I have a one year old son who sleeps besides my wife on her berth. He does not get his usual space which results in his sleep getting disturbed. He gets up a number of times crying and thus disturbing everyone. What are some techniques to make a baby sleep peacefully during an overnight train journey?

Comment: Book a berth for the baby as well?

Comment: cough syrup :D ...

Comment: Cannot book a separate berth. There is nothing at the side to protect him from falling.

Comment: @Nean: I can't say I have not thought about it :D

Comment: Book a berth + put the baby in a travel cot on the berth?

Comment: In my grandmother's day, rubbing a little whiskey on the baby's gums did the trick, but times have changed.

Comment: @JoErNanO Thank you so much, makes me feel good about being part of here

Comment: @skv My pleasure. :) Gotta wait a couple more hours before I can award it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, the comments have given a suggestion about booking another berth, which is impractical if you are concerned that the baby may actually roll over.

Some practical tips to consider

1. You can either book a first class or a 2-tier AC berth (if you are travelling 3 tier AC already and are considering a second ticket for the kid, it may work out cheaper to do this), and ensure that you get a lower berth (which is tough unless you book early), the berth in a 2-tier AC or First AC or First Class compartments are much wider than the one in other classes and can give enough room for the kid

If you really want this substantiated you can see (http://trainstuff.in/classes-of-travel) which has pictures and detailed measurements.

2. If you like to be a bit bold and can convince co-passenger the way I did with a year old daughter you can look to replicate what I did. I used to make a cradle in between the seats, I will have to draw up something to explain (and kindly forgive my horrible drawing), you tie a sufficiently long piece of cloth i.e. a saree or something that's circa 2 metres long and tie it up to the top berth, since the train only shakes sideways this would actually provide a very comfortable journey to the kid (if he is used to sleeping in those age old cradles made with a similar style at home it would be even better).

[image: self-made travel cradle]

3. The third option is to get two lower berths and actually carry a small flat cradle into the compartment and make the baby sleep in it, like this:

[image: travel cradle]

I have only thought about this never did this for my travels.

Happy sleeping